# How to set a loop with a timer that makes ajax requests until a response is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery:

```
    $.ajax('/contacts_imported', {
        dataType : 'json',
        data : {
            email : cfg.email
        },
        success : function(data) {
            if (data[0].processed) {
                alert('Processed is TRUE!');
            } else {
                alert('Not yet Processed');
            }

        }
    });
```

What I'm trying to do is, have this ajax request run every second until processed is equal to True. Once True, run a separate functions and kill the timer/loop.

How can I best handle this in an elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do NOT use an interval, as your AJAX request may take longer than 1 second every now and then.  So wrap your ajax in a function and call it like this:

```
(function makeRequest() {
    $.ajax('/contacts_imported', {
        dataType : 'json',
        data : {
            email : cfg.email
        },
        success : function(data) {
            if (data[0].processed) {
                alert('Processed is TRUE!');
            } else {
                setTimeout(makeRequest, 800);
            }
        }
    });
}());
```

Comment: Thanks but if the server is responding around 200ms which is going to make 5 requests a second right?

Comment: This plugin does essentially the same thing but allows for an interval to be set https://github.com/jeremyw/jquery-smart-poll

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer.  So if the request takes ~200ms on average, then simply delay the request by about 800ms.

Comment: @Bogdan - I think a plugin is a little overkill for this type of simple functionality.  What ever happened to writing extremely basic javascript?

Comment: @Ryan Wheale I agree. But I wasn't necessary suggesting him to use it, just having a look at the code could have given him an idea.

Comment: Thanks that works.. Ideally it could be counting the time required for the request and subtracting that from 0 to know when to make the next request..

Comment: That's impossible- here's a dumbed down version without he ajax request: http://jsfiddle.net/h26Zq/1/